# Видемость переменных в функциях php

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос.

Есть одна функция которую я могу вызвать несколькими способами назовем ее `test_1` в этой функции есть `preg_replace_callback($regexp, “test_2”, $str);`

Получилось у меня что то вроде такого

```php
function test_1($parameter_1){
  function test_2($parameter_2){
   $var = "Тут что то"; // переменную которую нужно передать
   return parameter_1[1] ... parameter_1[n]; // тут я возвращаю то что нужно для замены с помощью регулярки
  }
  $str_str = preg_replace_callback($regexp, "test_2", $str);
  $var; // сюда нужно передать значение из test_2
}
```

Вопрос как мне из функции `test_2` передать значение переменной `var` в функцию `test_1` для дальнейшей с ней работы? Значение переменной может меняться и использование `global` мне не подходит так как работает не корректно для обновления значения данной переменной.

Comment: повторный вызов test1 в такой реализации приведет к фатальной ошибке. Замените тест2 на анонимную функцию, а если при этом надо что-то куда-то сложить то в `use (&$out)` его и складывайте

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку ... вроде всё получилось. Вечером буду переписывать свой код

Comment: @Mister_X а что вообще вы пытаетесь сделать? Идея сопоставлять строки для замены и вычислять какую-то внешнюю переменную в одной функции выглядит не очень здорово. Может быть можно решить вашу задачу иначе?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Я разбираюсь просто с регуляркой. Вот к примеру данный форум для выделения полужирным текст нужно выделить двумя * в начале и двумя в конце для этого я так понимаю используются регуляки.

Comment: А так я уже изменил свой код с анонимной функцией и использовал как посоветовали выше `use (&$out)`